# How to enable cash Control Option in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Odoo 9 Documentation is showing cash control option in point of sale settings. But I can not find cash control option for point of sale settings. I have tried different configurations but no gain so far. I am looking for that Red Rectangle option :(

Anybody know how to enable the cash control option for point of sale. Or anybody can confirm if this option is available only for Enterprise version. I am using community version. Image is[image] attached for better understanding.

Thanks in advance. !!!

Comment: Jainik, i can't find this module. is this for odoo 9 ?

Comment: I have installed Generic - Accounting but nothing happened, I am still facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am  try to Explain in Technically You can see the latest Image Of the odoo 9 POS Configuration:

[image]

You can see the Boolean field is Define in **point_of_sale.py** file in GitHub original and Verified Source by Odoo.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/point_of_sale/point_of_sale.py#L109

You can see The Check-box Filed in the **point_of_sale_view.xml** file hear This is odoo Simply Display Fields.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/point_of_sale/point_of_sale_view.xml#L695

This fields Render In view To above line So This not any condition Define for visible and Invisible or not a set any attrs or domain in this filed so when POS install then this configuration is Show in this view.

So this Field is all time Display..

Thank you,